# Bazel iOS tests failing on Xcode 15

Tags: ios, bazel, xctest

I'm running some Bazel tests on Xcode 15 and have started seeing this new error (these tests are still passing on Xcode 14.3.1).

```
xcodebuild: error: Failed to build workspace temporary with scheme Transient Testing.: File is of an unsupported type; must be either an xctestrun file or xctestproducts bundle.
```

Could this be because the `xctestrun.py` file creates `xctestrun` files name `xctestrun.plist` without the normal `.xctestrun` suffix?

Answer (score 1):

It has [support](https://github.com/bazelbuild/continuous-integration/blob/7ac1c0cf5f381b9de993a3540c4de17f4751818e/buildkite/bazelci.py#L623) upto 14.3 only.I don't see any support for Xcode 15.